# apy key autentication in google map

Tags: api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've two site, when I used the google map.

The code is the same, and I use the same apy key, generater in 
https://console.developers.google.com/project/579752013451/apiui/credential?authuser=0

In the box referers I've specified both domains using the same method (*.domain.it/*), one for line.

In frist site the map run, in the second, the map say "Google ha disabilitato l'utilizzo della API di Google Maps per questa applicazione. La chiave fornita non è una Chiave API Google valida o non è autorizzata per l'API Javascript v3 di Google Maps su questo sito. Se sei il proprietario di questa applicazione, puoi trovare ulteriori informazioni su come ottenere una chiave valida qui: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key"

I tried to swap the order of the two domains, but the result is same.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any API-key anymore for version 3. And quoting from the second link you provide: "Google Maps API for Business developers must not include a key in their requests."
PS: It would be helpful for others if you would translate the error message.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: As of June 22, 2016, Gmaps requires an API key for any new usage of the web API.  Prior usages are grandfathered as of now.

Embedding the map is an exception to this new rule.